# Научиться проектировать архитектуру приложения

Tags: c#, книги, архитектура, проектирование

Стал замечать, что по мере освоения C#, я все больше думаю о том, как архитектурно реализовать ту или иную часть приложения.

Например, разрабатывая приложение для взаимодействия с USB-устройством, задумался над тем, а как именно будут взаимодействовать его компоненты.

Например, можно реализовать единственный класс, который будет заниматься всем: работать на уровне WinAPI с USB, ожидать прихода пакетов, понимать протокол общения, реализовывать последовательности команд и обработку ответов на них и т.д.

Но это неудобное решение. Лучше разделить по слоям и, например, вынести общение по USB в отдельный модуль и тогда, если USB поменяется на Ethernet, то можно будет просто написать новый модуль, не трогая остальное.

Окей, пишем модуль общения по USB. Для этого пишем сначала интерфейс взаимодействия с верхним уровнем. Написали. Так, что-то тут все заточено под синхронный обмен, а вдруг понадобится асинхронный. Дополняем. И еще несколько параметров.

Начинаем писать сам модуль. Оказывается, заложенная функциональность избыточна. А еще вот тут что-то не так и там и т.д. Опять начинаем думать, исправлять/дополнять.

В итоге я зарываюсь в вопросы из серии "а как лучше сделать сейчас, чтобы в будущем было удобно поддерживать?", производительность падает, а сложность придуманных конструкций резко растет и в итоге получается какая-то каша, а не идеальный код, который я и хотел получить.

Что я делаю не так? Как поступают опытные программисты? Как они избегают этих бесконечных вопросов и при этом пишут вполне поддерживаемый и понятный код?

Какую литературу можно почитать, чтобы прокачаться в этих вопросах? Шаблоны проектирования? А не слишком ли они заточены под крупные проекты и сложны для небольших проектов?

И есть ли у кого ссылки на проекты на C#, где можно посмотреть архитектурные решения?

Comment: как по мне то нужно идти от проблемы, а не от желания "что-то прикрутить". Лично я пользуюсь как справочником [http://citforum.ru/SE/project/pattern/][1]


  [1]: http://citforum.ru/SE/project/pattern/

Comment: Эти вопросы раскрываются в книгах посвященных "проектированию и разработке программного обеспечения": восходящее и нисходящее проектирование, модульная архитектура, паттерны, процесс разработки и т.д. Попробуйте почитать Брауде Э. Технология разработки программного обеспечения(сам я не читал) или поискать информацию по данной теме.

Comment: > Попробуйте почитать Брауде Э. Технология разработки программного обеспечения(сам я не читал)

Книга хороша.

Answer (score 5):

[@yabloko](/users/18354/yabloko), умение проектировать и находить баланс между текущими потребностями проекта и созданием задела на будущее приходит только с опытом. Нельзя просто прочитать книжку и обрести просветление. Поэтому пишите код, обдумывайте, изучайте как устроены чужие проекты, моделируйте какие-нибудь примеры взятые с потолка. Проектируйте для разминки небольшие "взятые с потолка" фрагменты функциональности. Просто на бумажке. Например:

- простенький UI из текстовых полей и кнопок, но такой, чтобы при необходимости можно было расширить количество виджетов;
- список контактов, с возможностью импорта из разных источников (почта, twitter, соцсети);
- текстовый редактор с простыми операциями над текстом (например, сделать выделенный фрагмент КАПСОМ) и возможностью их отмены.
- и т. п.

В общем фантазируйте и тренируйтесь.

Кстати про проектирование полноценного текстового редактора подробно разжевано в "Банде четырех".

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте думать в терминах сущностей и их ответственности. Какие сущности есть в вашей программе, кто за что отвечает, кто о чём знает? Если вы не можете описать одним коротким предложением ответственность модуля/класса/функции/переменной, возможно, её надо переделать.

Вы не должны думать о том, нужно ли будет подменить кусок с USB на кусок с Ethernet. Это может оказаться преждевременным дизайнерским решением, overengineering. Но вот разделение на отдельные простые слои — правильная мысль, она поможет вам бороться со сложностью проекта, сосредотачиваться каждый раз только на нужной части.

Точно так же, вы выделяете код в процедуру, если он имеет самостоятельный смысл, а не для повторного использования. Даже если процедура используется всего один раз.

Стоит почитать какую-нибудь книгу по паттернам, но не увлекайтесь этим сильно: свои мозги всяко лучше, чем консервированные идеи. Тем более, то, что в одном языке — паттерн, в другом часть синтаксиса (пример: Observer в C# реализуется в одно объявление, а в C++ требует уйму boilerplate-кода).

Comment: Ваш ответ заставил задуматься, спасибо! Вы не могли бы еще пояснить фразу *вы выделяете код в процедуру, если он имеет самостоятельный смысл, а не для повторного использования..* - часто же вроде код заключается в функцию, чтобы её потом вызывать где надо?... Или если код объединятся в функцию для повторного использования - это уже ошибка проектирования/конструирования?...

Comment: @VladimirBershov: Смотрите. Если какая-то часть кода является _самостоятельным логическим фрагментом_, то её уже стоит выделить в отдельную процедуру, даже если вы не будете её использовать повторно. А если вы какую-то часть кода используете повторно, то наверняка она тем более является самостоятельным логическим фрагментом.

Answer (score 0):

Читайте про паттерны программирования. Например, есть такая книжечка "Паттерны проектирования" авторы  Эрик Фримен, Элизабет Фримен, там на джаве все показывается, но суть понятна и для других языков. Еще есть куча литературы по паттернам. используйте их, практикуйтесь, и там постепенно придет понимание что и как делать.

Comment: если только про паттерны читать, можно паттерн головного мозга подхватить )